# login form won't get information from SQL database and store it in a session variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication, session-variables

i can not get my Login script to login...  i have an index.php with a register form and a login form, the register form works perfectly, but it seems like the login form does not get the information from the database when you enter the "login" button, when logging in you is redirectet to "home.php" which wil show your username with help of sessions. but i get this error "Notice: Undefined variable: username in home.php on line 12"... I think its because its not logging in and the session gets an undefined variabel. I just cant find where the problem is

i have a database named "thesozializer" 
and the sql for the table is:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`sign_up_date` date NOT NULL,
`activated` enum('0','1') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

index.php looks like this:

```js
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("couldn't connect to database.");
mysql_select_db("thesocializer") or die("couldn't select database");

$reg = @$_POST['reg'];
//declaring variables to prevent errors
$fn = ""; //First Name
$ln = ""; //Last Name
$un = ""; //Username
$em = ""; //Email
$em2 = ""; //Email 2
$pswd = ""; //Password
$pswd2 = ""; // Password 2
$d = ""; // Sign up Date
$u_check = ""; // Check if username exists
//registration form
$fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
$ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
$un = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
$em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);
$pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);
$d = date("Y-m-d"); // Year - month - day

if ($reg) {
if ($em==$em2) {
// Check if user already exists
$u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");
// Count the amount of rows where username = $un
$check = mysql_num_rows($u_check);
//Check whether Email already exists in the database
$e_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$em'");
//Count the number of rows returned
$email_check = mysql_num_rows($e_check);
if ($check == 0) {
  if ($email_check == 0) {
//check all of the fields have been filed in
if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2) {
// check that passwords match
if ($pswd==$pswd2) {
// check the maximum length of username/first name/last name does not exceed 25 characters
if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {
echo "maximum length of username/first name/last name is 25 characters!";
}
else
{
// check the maximum length of password does not exceed 25 characters and is not less than 5 characters
if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {
echo "Password must be between 5 and 25 characters!";
}
else
{
//encrypt password and password 2 using md5 before sending to database
$pswd = md5($pswd);
$pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
die("<h2>welcome to The Socializer!</h2>Login to get started");
}
}
}
else {
echo "your passwords is incorrect";
}
}
else
{
echo "fill in all fields";
}
}
else
{
 echo "email already in use";
}
}
else
{
echo "username already in use";
}
}
else {
echo "The emails is not alike!";
}
}

//User Login Code

if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
 $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]);
 $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]);
 $password_login_md5 = md5($password_login);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$password_login_md5' LIMIT 1");
 //Check for their existance
 $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned
 if ($userCount == 1) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   $id = $row["id"];
 }
  
  $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
  header("location: home.php");
  exit();
  } 
  else {
  echo 'username or password is incorrect';
  exit();
 }
}

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {

}
else
{
 $username = $_SESSION["user_login"];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#registrer-deg").click(function(){
        $("#registrerdeg").show();
      });
      $("#registrer-deg").click(function(){
        $("#logginn").hide();
     });
    $("#logg-inn").click(function(){
        $("#logginn").show();
      });
      $("#logg-inn").click(function(){
        $("#registrerdeg").hide();
    }); 
   });
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
  <title>The Socializer</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="sidebarLeft">
   <div id="logo"></div>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="logg-inn">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="registrer-deg">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="timeline">
   <div id="registrering">
    <form id="registrerdeg" action="index.php" method="POST" style="display: none;">
     <input type="text" name="fname" size="10" placeholder="First name"><br/>
     <input type="text" name="lname" size="10" placeholder="Last name"><br/>
     <input type="text" name="username" size="10" placeholder="Username"><br/>
     <input type="text" name="email" size="10" placeholder="Email"><br/>
     <input type="text" name="email2" size="10" placeholder="Confirm email"><br/>
     <input type="text" name="password" size="10" placeholder="Password"><br/>
     <input type="text" name="password2" size="10" placeholder="Confirm Password"><br/>
     <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Registrer!">
    </form>
   </div>
   <div id="logg_inn">
    <form id="logginn" action="index.php" method="POST" style="display: none;">
     <input type="text" name="user_login" size="10" placeholder="Username"><br/>
     <input type="text" name="password_login" size="10" placeholder="Password"><br/>
     <input type="submit" name="login" value="Logg inn!">
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
 background-color: #2C3E50;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #AFEEEE;
}

#sidebarLeft {
 width: 220px;
 height: 550px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 position: fixed;
}

#sidebarRight {
 width: 220px;
 height: 550px;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 position: fixed;
}

ul {
 width: 220px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

li {
 height: 35px;
 width: 220px;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 5px;
}

#logo {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background-image: url("../img/logo.png");
 -moz-border-radius: 75px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 750px;
 border-radius: 75px;
 margin-left: 35px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

#sidebarLeft ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 9px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #AFEEEE;
}

#timeline {
 width: 780px;
 height: 550px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 240px;
 top: 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
 margin-top: 3px;
 outline: none;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 font-weight: normal;
}

:-moz-input-placeholder {
 font-weight: normal;
}

::-moz-input-placeholder {
 font-weight: normal;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
 font-weight: normal;
}

input[type="submit"] {
   border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
   background: #61a6d4;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#316c94), to(#61a6d4));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #316c94, #61a6d4);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #316c94, #61a6d4);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #316c94, #61a6d4);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #316c94, #61a6d4);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
   -moz-border-radius: 7px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
   border-top-color: #49718c;
   background: #49718c;
   color: #ccc;
}

input[type="submit"]:active {
   border-top-color: #1b435e;
   background: #1b435e;
}
```

and home.php looks like this:

```js
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("couldn't connect to database.");
mysql_select_db("thesocializer") or die("couldn't select database");

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {

}
else
{
 $username = $_SESSION["user_login"];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
  <title>The Socializer</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="sidebarLeft">
   <div id="logo">
   </div>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="logg-inn">Logg inn</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="registrer-deg">Registrer deg</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Om</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="timeline">
   <?php echo "Hello, ".$username; ?>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
 background-color: #2C3E50;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #AFEEEE;
}

#sidebarLeft {
 width: 220px;
 height: 550px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 position: fixed;
}

#sidebarRight {
 width: 220px;
 height: 550px;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 position: fixed;
}

ul {
 width: 220px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

li {
 height: 35px;
 width: 220px;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 5px;
}

#logo {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background-image: url("../img/logo.png");
 -moz-border-radius: 75px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 750px;
 border-radius: 75px;
 margin-left: 35px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

#sidebarLeft ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 9px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #AFEEEE;
}

#timeline {
 width: 780px;
 height: 550px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 240px;
 top: 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
 margin-top: 3px;
 outline: none;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 font-weight: normal;
}

:-moz-input-placeholder {
 font-weight: normal;
}

::-moz-input-placeholder {
 font-weight: normal;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
 font-weight: normal;
}

input[type="submit"] {
   border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
   background: #61a6d4;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#316c94), to(#61a6d4));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #316c94, #61a6d4);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #316c94, #61a6d4);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #316c94, #61a6d4);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #316c94, #61a6d4);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
   -moz-border-radius: 7px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
   border-top-color: #49718c;
   background: #49718c;
   color: #ccc;
}

input[type="submit"]:active {
   border-top-color: #1b435e;
   background: #1b435e;
}
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and REALLY need to learn how to properly format your code. You've got if() statements nested however many levels deep, without a single indentation to make it easier to read. Using `@` is the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you".

Comment: narrow it down, dont expect us to read 300+ lines of your code.

Comment: If I write *tl;dr* ... does that make me a bad person?

Comment: You're calling `session_start` _after_ the redirect. It needs to be called first in order to add things to the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to move the `session_start();` 
in both pages at the begin of your script.

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("couldn't connect to database.");
...
```

home.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("couldn't connect to database.");
...
```